# Spring listener cotainer - create and stay idle upon explicit start

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I was looking for way to create spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer
and put it initially into "idle" state and start it explicitly.

Now, I've found a way through autoStartup property
and of course setting it as p:autoStartup="false". 
Like:

```
<bean id="mqLsnr" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
          p:connectionFactory-ref="cf"
          p:messageListener-ref="lsnr"
          p:destinationName="someQueue"
          p:acceptMessagesWhileStopping="false"
          p:autoStartup="false"/>
```

My scenario is that I have two clustered nodes where I would like
listener to be prepared and stay idle until explicitly started (by other means 
what is not relevant for discussion).

Does anyone has better suggestion/idea/tip as such would be 
very welcome and appreciated.

I understand that this question is not very best suited for stackoverflow
but spring crew chose it as alternative to their forums where I'd post
it otherwise.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone has better suggestion...

This is the proper technique; what do you perceive as being an issue (the reason for needing a "better" solution) ?

Comment: Well, being issue would be primary my uncertainity about using method present for purpose of plumbing into container lifecycle for such use as I haven't so far gone through complete implementation of default listener container (what I am doing now/meanwhile).
So, I simply wanted to check if someone could suggest something better. Meanwhile I am still testing and collecting output looking for issues.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after testing for a while, this seems to work quite OK.
So if no one has some objection this could be closed :)